# Pie chart not rendering at ext panel (EXT JS)

Tags: javascript, extjs

My pie chart is not rendering - this is my code below.

I've rendered it below the last part of code, it is still not rendering. Or it is not possible to draw it inside new Ext panel? Please help as I don't know how to debug this anymore.

```
 <div id="ae_chart_tb"></div>
    <div style="height: 95%;">
      <div id="ae_chart" style="height: 50%;"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      Ext.chart.Chart.CHART_URL = 'charts.swf';
      var tb = new Ext.Toolbar();

      var ae_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/chart_attendance_exception/data',
        root: 'data',
        fields: ['Type', 'Total'],
        autoLoad: false
      });
    
      function loadChartStore(store){
        store.load({
          params:{
            from_date: Ext.getCmp('ae_from_date').getValue(),
            to_date: Ext.getCmp('ae_to_date').getValue(),
            unit_id: Ext.getCmp('ae_units').getValue()
          }
        });
      }
    
     var ae_pie_chart = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Subordinates\' Attendance Exception Chart',
        height: 300,
        renderTo: 'ae_chart',
        items: {
          store: ae_store,
          xtype: 'piechart',
          dataField: 'Total',
          categoryField: 'Type',
          //extra styles get applied to the chart defaults
          extraStyle:
          {
            legend:
            {
              display: 'bottom',
              padding: 5,
              font:
              {
                family: 'Tahoma',
                size: 13
              }
            }
          }
        },
        listeners:{
          afterrender: function(){
            loadChartStore(ae_store);
          }
        }
      });
      t = document.getElementById("ae_chart_tb");
      tb.render(t);
    
    ae_pie_chart.render();
    ae_pie_chart.syncSize();
```

Comment: 1. May your reproduce the bug in the http://fiddle.sencha.com ? I see the swf, have you checked the browser for swf support? Some browsers already do not support swf in default settings..

Comment: Flash is dead. Therefore this question is rather pointless.

Comment: yes @MartinZeitler you are right

Comment: btw i have already solved this problem

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/syslogic/extjs-nvd3-charts (a project of mine).

Comment: thankyou @MartinZeitler